# Can this code be made shorter?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programing/development and have just basic knowledge of Java but many years in different languages such as PHP, JavaScript and some C#. I'm just wondering can I make this code shorter like into one line? Without making another variable called "test" just for test purposes.. and then use that one variable for whatever I would like to such as auth system.

```
public void signIn(View view) {

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
    String test = username.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: The goal of programming isn't to make things as short as possible.  Its to make your code as readable and maintainable as possible.  This code is highly readable, making it shorter wouldn't make it better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about codereview and should be ask at [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
public void signIn(View view) {

    String test =  ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameField)).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Why did you stop there? You can inline `test` the same why you eliminated `username`.

Comment: I eliminated username as in the mentioned question . I wrote it in one line.

Answer (score 1):

use [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).

- Eliminate `findViewById` calls by using `@BindView` on fields.
- Group multiple views in a list or array. Operate on all of them at once with actions, setters, or properties.
- Eliminate anonymous inner-classes for listeners by annotating methods with `@OnClick` and others.
- Eliminate resource lookups by using resource annotations on fields.

```
@BindView(R.id.usernameField)
EditText username;

...
public void signIn(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, username.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

//this is declare as global in the class

```
@BindView(R.id.usernameField) TextView title;
```

// basic one is declare in onCreate

```
EditText username;
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField); // in onCreate
```

Another alternative library - [Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: Can you please explain me what it is and why should I use that "ButterKnife"?